# After using and customizing Flutter ExtendedTextFeild Pakage, when the word is highlighted, the cursor goes to the start of the text field

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-packages

I wanted to highlight the text in a textfeild when a word is start from a particular character. For that I used **extended_text_field** pakage(https://pub.dev/packages/extended_text_field).
I modify the AtText class and create HashText so that the word starting from hash(#) should be highlighted. But the issue is that when I type any #word or @word then the cursor is moved to the start of the line.
The AtText Class is

```
import 'package:extended_text_field/extended_text_field.dart';
import 'package:flutter/gestures.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class AtText extends SpecialText {
  static const String flag = "@";
  final int start;

  /// whether show background for @somebody
  final bool showAtBackground;

  AtText(TextStyle textStyle, SpecialTextGestureTapCallback onTap,
      {this.showAtBackground: false, this.start})
      : super(
          flag,
          " ",
          textStyle,
        );

  @override
  InlineSpan finishText() {
    TextStyle textStyle =
        this.textStyle?.copyWith(color: Colors.blue, fontSize: 16.0);

    final String atText = toString();

    return showAtBackground
        ? BackgroundTextSpan(
            background: Paint()..color = Colors.blue.withOpacity(0.15),
            text: atText,
            actualText: atText,
            start: start,

            ///caret can move into special text
            deleteAll: true,
            style: textStyle,
            recognizer: (TapGestureRecognizer()
              ..onTap = () {
                if (onTap != null) onTap(atText);
              }))
        : SpecialTextSpan(
            text: atText,
            actualText: atText,
            start: start,
            style: textStyle,
            recognizer: (TapGestureRecognizer()
              ..onTap = () {
                if (onTap != null) onTap(atText);
              }));
  }
}
```

And the HashText class is

```
import 'package:extended_text_field/extended_text_field.dart';
import 'package:flutter/gestures.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class HashText extends SpecialText {
  static const String flag = "#";
  final int start;

  /// whether show background for #something
  final bool showAtBackground;

  HashText(TextStyle textStyle, SpecialTextGestureTapCallback onTap,
      {this.showAtBackground: false, this.start})
      : super(
          flag,
          " ",
          textStyle,
        );

  @override
  InlineSpan finishText() {
    TextStyle textStyle =
        this.textStyle?.copyWith(color: Colors.blue, fontSize: 16.0);

    final String atText = toString();

    return showAtBackground
        ? BackgroundTextSpan(
            background: Paint()..color = Colors.blue.withOpacity(0.15),
            text: atText,
            actualText: atText,
            start: start,

            ///caret can move into special text
            deleteAll: true,
            style: textStyle,
            recognizer: (TapGestureRecognizer()
              ..onTap = () {
                if (onTap != null) onTap(atText);
              }))
        : SpecialTextSpan(
            text: atText,
            actualText: atText,
            start: start,
            style: textStyle,
            recognizer: (TapGestureRecognizer()
              ..onTap = () {
                if (onTap != null) onTap(atText);
              }));
  }
}
```